# Realtime Bi-direction Socket

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, real-time

I have an Arduino loaded with sensors connected to a Raspberry Pi. The Arduino passes all the data from the sensors to Raspberry.

Now I want to push all of these data in real-time over a socket to a server in the backend, and upload the data into a database.

I'm looking for the most optimal solution for this. [Socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io) seems like a popular solution and relies on WebSockets and NodeJS.

[Pusher](https://pusher.com/) seems like a decent API service that can easily integrate into iOS and Android devices.

What is the best solution out here? It seems like WebSocket is the way to go, but is there a better protocol to use for this purpose?

Comment: Checkout the [Realtime Messaging](http://framework.realtime.co/messaging) service. It's similar to Pusher (with a slightly better pricing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the MQTT protocol as well. It's becoming widely used for this kind of purpose. You can find both open-source and commercial, as well as cloud-based and self-hosted, MQTT brokers.